# Express Session is not storing in redis using Expression session - connect redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, router

Does anybody have working code for Expression session storing in Redis ?

Iam creating angular 4 login page. i want to store user session in Redis by using Express session.

Iam getting error session is undefined

how can i view the sessionID in Redis ?

Iam struck with this. Does any body faced same issue? thanks for your help

Comment: Iam trying this from last 2 days and not getting. thanks your help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using `express-session` and `connect-redis`.

A complete example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const session = require('express-session');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

// Create redis client
const redis = require('redis');
// default client tries to get 127.0.0.1:6379
// (a redis instance should be running there)
const client = redis.createClient();
client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
client.on('connect', function (err) {
  console.log('connected to redis successfully');
});

// Initialize middleware passing your client
// you can specify the way you save the sessions here
app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({client: client}),
  secret: 'some secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // that's how you get the session id from each request
  console.log('session id:', req.session.id)
  // the session will be automatically stored in Redis with the key prefix 'sess:'
  const sessionKey = `sess:${req.session.id}`;
  // let's see what is in there
  client.get(sessionKey, (err, data) => {
    console.log('session data in redis:', data)
  })
  res.status(200).send('OK');
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server running on port 3000')
})

/*
If you check your redis server with redis-cli, you will see that the entries are being added:
$ redis-cli --scan --pattern 'sess:*'
*/
```

For further information you might want to read [this](https://github.com/expressjs/session#session-store-implementation) and [this](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am also using express-session and connect-redis. I tried your code  to fetch from redis ,    client.get(sessionKey, (err, data) => {
    console.log('session data in redis:', data)
  })     . But it  returns null .  It is not storing in redis.  I am not sure where the session is getting stored.

Comment: What does the `err` object from `client.get()` output? @Jan

Comment: Error also return 'Null".

Comment: And you are able to see the console log `connected to redis successfully`?
Can you access your local redis instance with `redis-cli` from the command line?

Comment: Yes, Redis is connecting and able do access redis instance from command line.

Comment: Can you try this:
`  const getData = function() {
    client.get(sessionKey, (err, data) => {
      console.log('redis data:', data); 
    })};
  setTimeout(getData, 3000)
`

instead of:
`
client.get(sessionKey, (err, data) => {
    console.log('session data in redis:', data)
  })
`

Also to see it in redis itself, after the request to the express server, copy the given `sessionKey`, go to `redis-cli` and write `get the_pasted_key`

Comment: I used above code and redis data is null. before above code i put log for sessionID console.log('session id:', req.session.id) and sessionID is displying on my application console. but in redis cli if try with the keys * , then no session found. Note: Iam not using app.get('/') as iam using below:
router.post('/login/:username/:password', function (req, res) {

Comment: I am having exactly the same behavior. Connected to redis properly (confirmed). But session data is not stored into the redis at all (I cannot see any keys over there). @Jan